# Resultado NaN del sumatio de una array

Tags: javascript

tengo este codigo(un como liado porque he ido probando):

```
const calculatorPro = () => {
  let numberList = [];
  let newNumber;
  let loopBreak = true;
  let sum;

  while(loopBreak === true){
    
      newNumber = parseFloat(prompt('Enter a number or write stop when you don\'t enter more number.'));
      parseInt(newNumber);
      numberList.push(newNumber);
      
      
      
  if(isNaN(newNumber)){
      loopBreak = false;
  }
  if((newNumber === '' || isNaN(newNumber)) && loopBreak === true){
      alert('Is not a number, please enter a number.')
  } }


  
  for(let i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++){
  
      for(let j = 0; j < numberList.length; j++ ){

      sum = parseFloat(numberList[i] + numberList[j]);
  
  }
}

  parseInt(sum);
// const sum = numberList.reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a, 0);
      
// const rest = numberList.reduce((partial_rest, a) => partial_rest - a, 0);
      
// const multiply = numberList.reduce((partial_multi, a) => partial_multi * a, 0);
      
// const divide = numberList.reduce((partial_div, a) => partial_div / a, 0);

  
  if(numberList.length === 1){
      console.log('The result of the square root: ' + (Math.sqrt(numberList[0])).toFixed(3));
  }else if(numberList.length > 1){
      
      console.log(`The result of the sum is ${sum}`);
      // console.log(`The result of the rest is ${rest.toFixed(3)}`);
      // console.log(`The result of the multiply is ${multiply.toFixed(3)}`);
      // console.log(`The result of the divide is ${divide.toFixed(3)}`)
  }
  
}
  
  
calculatorPro();
```

es una calculadora que pide datos en un prompt hadsta que el usuario cancela el prompt, quiero hacer un suma, resta, multiplicacion y division de el array donde se almacena los datos. He probado con una funcion y .reduce/ bucle for anidado, en los dos casos me da como resultado NaN.
PD:he puesto parseInt y parseFloat hasta en el sobaco.

Comment: Hay una forma muy simple de forzar un valor. Supongamos que `unInt` tiene que ser un número sí o sí, pues cuando haces el parse pones esto: `var unInt=parseInt(elValor)||0;` y `unInt` valdrá `0` cuando no satisfaga las condiciones de número (evitando el `NaN` que signifca *Not a Number*). Por ejemplo aquí: `var elValor='XYZ'; var unInt=parseInt(elValor)||0;` no tendrás `NaN`, sino `0`, y por tanto, un entero válido para cualquier operación, menos la división, en cuyo caso debes controlar el posible error de división por `0`.

Comment: Por favor, revisa tu pregunta, porque resulta difícil entender qué necesitas. También facilitaría las cosas que redactaras con un mínimo de cuidado a nivel ortográfico y gramatical… 
Si tú misma/o no le pones un mínimo de esfuerzo a tu pregunta, no invitas al resto a esforzarse en darte una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario aceptar diferentes tipos de entrada desde el prompt (null/string/number) y ajustar el comportamiento en consecuencia. He simplificado un poco tu aplicación. Echa un vistazo:

```js
const getUserInput = () => {
  const userInput = prompt('Please enter a number:\n(press "cancel" or write "stop" to finish');
  
  return userInput?.toLowerCase().trim() === 'stop' ? null : userInput;
};

const getUserNumbers = () => {
  const numbers = [];

  while(true) {
    const userValue = getUserInput();
    
    if (!userValue) break;
    
    const number = +userValue.replace(',', '.');
    
    if (isNaN(number)) {
      alert('The entered value in not a valid number!');
    } else {
      numbers.push(number);
    }
  }
  
  return numbers;
};

const runCalculator = () => {
  const numbers = getUserNumbers();
  
  if (numbers.lenght) {
    alert('No valid numbers were entered.');
  } else {
    const addition = numbers.reduce((acc, cur) => acc += cur);
    const subtraction = numbers.reduce((acc, cur) => acc -= cur);
    const multiplication = numbers.reduce((acc, cur) => acc *= cur);
    const division = numbers.reduce((acc, cur) => acc /= cur);
    const result = `
      Addition: ${addition}
      Subtraction: ${subtraction}
      Multiplication: ${multiplication}
      Division: ${division}
    `;
    
    alert(result);
  }
};

runCalculator();
```